# How to use async call inside forEach when using firebase calls

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, vuejs2

the question that I have is that I can't figure out how to make this code work properly using Firestore (not sure if this is irrelevant).

The actual code is the following:

```
prestamoItems() {
      var myarray = [];
      var myobject = {};

      //here comes the first async method (works OK)

      fb.prestamosCollection
        .orderBy("fechaPrestamo", "desc")
        .get()
        .then(val => {
          if (!val.empty) {

            //here comes forEach

            val.docs.forEach(doc => {
              myobject = doc.data();
              myobject.id = doc.id;
              console.log("The doc id is " +myobject.id)

              //here comes second async call inside the forEach loop, but it doesnt wait for this 
              //to be finished, and immediately goes to the other step

              fb.equiposCollection.doc(myobject.id).get().then(eqp => {
                console.log("The doc id from the other collection is " +eqp.id)
              })

              myarray.push(myobject)
              console.log("myobject pushed to myarray")
            });


          }
        });
    }
```

Please note that I'm calling an async method inside a forEach loop that comes from another async method. In every variation of the code, the output that I'm getting (the console logs) are the following:

```
11:13:14.999 Prestamos.vue?18d2:71 The doc id is 1yTCUKwBvlopXX2suvVu
11:13:14.999 Prestamos.vue?18d2:78 myobject pushed to myarray
11:13:15.000 Prestamos.vue?18d2:71 The doc id is Z5TE15Fj3HFrn1zvceGe
11:13:15.000 Prestamos.vue?18d2:78 myobject pushed to myarray
11:13:15.000 Prestamos.vue?18d2:71 The doc id is JNN9aN65XE1tUTmlzkoJ
11:13:15.000 Prestamos.vue?18d2:78 myobject pushed to myarray
11:13:15.000 Prestamos.vue?18d2:71 The doc id is NF2hHCpM8leZezHbmnJx
11:13:15.001 Prestamos.vue?18d2:78 myobject pushed to myarray
11:13:15.364 Prestamos.vue?18d2:74 The doc id from the other collection is 1yTCUKwBvlopXX2suvVu
11:13:15.368 Prestamos.vue?18d2:74 The doc id from the other collection is Z5TE15Fj3HFrn1zvceGe
11:13:15.374 Prestamos.vue?18d2:74 The doc id from the other collection is JNN9aN65XE1tUTmlzkoJ
11:13:15.379 Prestamos.vue?18d2:74 The doc id from the other collection is NF2hHCpM8leZezHbmnJx
```

So, the forEach loop is not waiting to the async function inside it (which actually is the expected behavior, AFAIK).

The question is how can I make it wait for the inner call to be finished before adding the obect to the array? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Place the adding to array inside your `then`..

Comment: Still the same result, even having the push inside the second then()

Comment: OP, I assume you intend to use `myarray` after pushing elements to it. How will you use it?

Comment: I'm going to place the results inside a bootstrap vue table (b-table) after returning myarray

Answer (score 1):

either you nest code, which depends on previous results into `then()` callbacks or you wrap the loop (`forEach` does not support async) in `async` block to make use of `await` inside. eg.:

```
fb.prestamosCollection
  .orderBy("fechaPrestamo", "desc")
    .get()
    .then(val => {
      if (!val.empty) {
        // wrap loop in async function call iife so we can use await inside
        (async () => {
          for (var i = 0; i < val.docs.length; i++) {
            const doc = val.docs[i];
            myobject = doc.data();
            myobject.id = doc.id;
            // this will be synchronous now
            let eqp = await fb.equiposCollection.doc(myobject.id).get();
            console.log(eqp.id);
            myarray.push(myobject)
          }
        })();
      }
    });
```

Comment: This code isn't going to work as you expect. The `await` call will suspend the for loop, meaning that the async code will execute sequentially rather than in parallel. additionally, if the OP attempts to access `myarray` outside of the `.then()`, this code won't work at all (which is why in my answer I do away with `myarray` entirely)

Comment: it is exactly how I expect it to work. I even wrote in the comment that it is synchronous. It is just not clear, what OP really wants to achieve. As I understood, he wanted to wait for the get() function before adding to the array, which is exactly what is happening in my example.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding me. He said in his comment that he will be returning `myarray` (posted a few seconds after your answer) and this code doesn't support that. Also, *synchronous* is not quite the right word.. this code will still be *asynchronous*. but it will execute in parallel, not concurrently. this means with a list of 5 items you will have 5 round trips to the db one after another, with each one waiting for the previous one to complete before continuing. If this *is* what you intended then I have to question why you wrote it this way.

Answer (score 1):

The root of the problem is that you're trying to turn an asychronous operation (waiting for Firestore to return values) into a synchronous one. This isn't really possible in a meaningful way in JavaScript without causing lots of issues!

You'll need to populate your array inside of the `.then()` callback and *return the promise* as a result of the function. Any caller that calls your `prestamoItems()` function will also have to use `.then()` callbacks to access the underlying `myarray` value:

```
const _ = {
  async prestamoItems() {
    const val = await fb.prestamosCollection.orderBy("fechaPrestamo", "desc").get();
    if (val.empty) {
      return myarray
    }

    // Promise.all() will take a list of promises and will return their results once they have all finished.
    return await Promise.all(
      // Array.prototype.map() will take an existing array and, for each item, call the given function and return a new array with the return value of each function in that array.
      // This is functionally equivalent to making a new array and push()ing to it, but it reads a lot nicer!
      val.docs.map(async doc => {
        const myobject = doc.data();
        const eqp = await fp.equiposCollection.doc(myobject.id).get()
        // I presume you want to do something with eqp here
        return myobject
      })
    );
  }
}
```

The above code sample uses `Array.prototype.map()` to do away with `myarray` as it's not necessary.

A caller would have to use this code like this:

```
_.prestamoItems().then((myarray) => {
   ...
})
```

---

Promises are a way of saying that a value may be avaliable at some point in the future. Because of this, you have to make sure that any interaction you have with a promise is written in such a way that assumes the value is not avaliable *immediately*. The easiest way to do this is by using `async`/`await` and ensuring that you return promise objects.

Comment: This is a good answer, but the accepted answer has a simpler structure. Thanks anyway, your help is very appreciated

Comment: The accepted answer also functions differently: it will fetch each item from the DB in *sequence*, not in parallel, so will be much slower

Comment: I've been working with the accepted answer and you're right, It is going to be sequential, so it's going to be much slower than expected on large collections (I have a small collection right now just for testing purposes). I'm going to modify my code as you suggest

Answer (score 0):

just move the push inside then like this

```
fb.equiposCollection.doc(myobject.id).get().then(eqp => {
   console.log("The doc id from the other collection is " +eqp.id)

   myarray.push(myobject)
   console.log("myobject pushed to myarray")
})
```